# Cannot access object properties in handlebars partial

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, partials, express-handlebars

I'm working on nodejs application. And want to display Mongoose result in web page. Template engine is express handlebars.

```
   data=  [
              {name: 'some name', image: '/some_name.jpg', location: 'some location'},
              {name: 'some name2', image: '/some_name2.jpg', location: 'some location2'},
              {name: 'some name3', image: '/some_name3.jpg', location: 'some location3'}
           ]
```

I want to render data in handlebars partial. At first I'm iterating each object using `#each` and passing that object into the partial. Below is code how I'm doing.

```
{{#each data}}
   {{> somePartial this}} 
{{/each}}
```

In `somePartial` I want to access properties of the object.

```
 <h5>Name: {{this.name}}</h5>
 <h5>Image: {{this.image}}</h5>
 <h5>Location: {{this.location}}</h5>
```

I can't see any value rendering in browser. In server console I get some warning or something  like this **Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property 'xxxx' because it is not 'own property' of its parent.**.

Comment: Should it not be `{{#each data}}`?

Comment: I foget to put there.. now see

Answer (score 0):

Just use without **this**

```
{{> somePartial}}
```

...

```
<h5>Name: {{name}}</h5>
```

More info here: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-parameters

Answer (score 0):

To solve  **Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property 'xxxx' because it is not 'own property' of its parent.**

Map the result array in new array.

```
let result2 = result.map(val=>{
  return {field1: val.field1,field2: val.field2, field3: val.field3 and so on}
})
```

For security reason handlebar does not allow to pass fetched result directly. You need to map with required field so that no sensitive data got passed.